# liquibase.exception.DatabaseException in Liquibase

Tags: indexoutofboundsexception, liquibase

In Liquibase whenever I go for `generateChangeLog` for large database it give me error while for small database it run fine.

My error console is as follow:

**Command to cmd:**

```
   E:\liquibase-3.3.1-bin>liquibase 
   --driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver 
   --classpath=mysql-connector-java-5.1.6-bin.jar 
   --changeLogFile=xml\test11.xml 
   --url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:4928/test" 
   --username=root 
   --password=root 
   --diffTypes="tables,columns, foreignkeys,primarykeys, uniqueconstraints,
    data" generateChangeLog
```

**Error:**
    Unexpected error running Liquibase: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: java.lang.StringIndexOutO
    fBoundsException: String index out of range: -1

**FULL TRACKTRACE:**

```
liquibase: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
liquibase.exception.LiquibaseException: liquibase.command.CommandExecutionException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.CommandLineUtils.doGenerateChangeLog(CommandLineUtils.java:155)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.doMigration(Main.java:939)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.run(Main.java:177)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.main(Main.java:96)
Caused by: liquibase.command.CommandExecutionException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
        at liquibase.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:13)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.CommandLineUtils.doGenerateChangeLog(CommandLineUtils.java:153)
        ... 3 more
Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
        at liquibase.snapshot.jvm.ColumnSnapshotGenerator.snapshotObject(ColumnS
napshotGenerator.java:69)
        at liquibase.snapshot.jvm.JdbcSnapshotGenerator.snapshot(JdbcSnapshotGen
erator.java:60)
        at liquibase.snapshot.SnapshotGeneratorChain.snapshot(SnapshotGeneratorC
hain.java:50)
        at liquibase.snapshot.DatabaseSnapshot.include(DatabaseSnapshot.java:163
)
        at liquibase.snapshot.DatabaseSnapshot.replaceObject(DatabaseSnapshot.ja
va:241)
        at liquibase.snapshot.DatabaseSnapshot.includeNestedObjects(DatabaseSnap
shot.java:195)
        at liquibase.snapshot.DatabaseSnapshot.include(DatabaseSnapshot.java:177
)
        at liquibase.snapshot.DatabaseSnapshot.replaceObject(DatabaseSnapshot.ja
va:241)
        at liquibase.snapshot.DatabaseSnapshot.replaceObject(DatabaseSnapshot.ja
va:263)
        at liquibase.snapshot.DatabaseSnapshot.includeNestedObjects(DatabaseSnap
shot.java:195)
        at liquibase.snapshot.DatabaseSnapshot.include(DatabaseSnapshot.java:177
)
        at liquibase.snapshot.DatabaseSnapshot.init(DatabaseSnapshot.java:60)
        at liquibase.snapshot.DatabaseSnapshot.<init>(DatabaseSnapshot.java:37)
        at liquibase.snapshot.JdbcDatabaseSnapshot.<init>(JdbcDatabaseSnapshot.j
ava:25)
        at liquibase.snapshot.SnapshotGeneratorFactory.createSnapshot(SnapshotGe
neratorFactory.java:126)
        at liquibase.snapshot.SnapshotGeneratorFactory.createSnapshot(SnapshotGe
neratorFactory.java:119)
        at liquibase.command.DiffCommand.createReferenceSnapshot(DiffCommand.jav
a:190)
        at liquibase.command.DiffCommand.createDiffResult(DiffCommand.java:140)
        at liquibase.command.GenerateChangeLogCommand.run(GenerateChangeLogComma
nd.java:45)
        at liquibase.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:8)
        ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range:
 -1
        at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source)
        at liquibase.util.SqlUtil.parseValue(SqlUtil.java:101)
        at liquibase.snapshot.jvm.ColumnSnapshotGenerator.readDefaultValue(Colum
nSnapshotGenerator.java:345)
        at liquibase.snapshot.jvm.ColumnSnapshotGenerator.readColumn(ColumnSnaps
hotGenerator.java:200)
        at liquibase.snapshot.jvm.ColumnSnapshotGenerator.snapshotObject(ColumnS
napshotGenerator.java:45)
        ... 23 more
```

Comment: Do you have a more detailed stacktrace?

Comment: I do not have more detail stacktrace but I noticed that whenever I go for generateChangeLog process for many tables(arround 900-1200) in which if any table has lots of entry(more than 50000 rows) at that time I got this exception. In my db there are 3000 tables and many tables have lots of data. One ore thing if I ignore those large tables then its working

Comment: If you run with --logLevel=DEFAULT it should give you a better stacktrace

Comment: see my edit for detailed stacktrace.

Comment: Also we have enum data type of column  in many  table

Comment: Cant do anything with what you have provided.  Theres probably a rogue entry in your 50000 rows causing the problem.

Comment: Can you please provide solution for enum data type? because of enum type  we are getting erros

Comment: Sorry, I don't see where in the code of [liquibase.snapshot.jvm.ColumnSnapshotGenerator.snapshotObject](liquibase-core/src/main/java/liquibase/snapshot/jvm/ColumnSnapshotGenerator.java) a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` could happen.
But also, `generateChangeLog` just generates the db schema and should not have anything to do with how much data is inside the tables (at least not to my knowledge).
Maybe you could start with what is working add add more tables until it breaks then you might be able to isolate the table/column/view that is causing this.

Comment: Sorry link in my previous comment is broken (and edit time for comment has passed). Here's another try: [ColumnSnapshotGenerator.snapshotObject](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/deea21e8a3cc75cd87cccf5ae264a4ce25074ffc/liquibase-core/src/main/java/liquibase/snapshot/jvm/ColumnSnapshotGenerator.java)

Answer (score 2):

According to [the comment of Sergei Visotsky](https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-3360) this exception seems to appear when database views are present.

In my case dropping the views solved the issue.